# Moving my newly made site from subdirectory

Tags: migration

so i have currently finished making my website in the subdirectory and now it is time to move it over to my main domain. At the moment it is in example.com/wordpress and i want it to be moved to example.com Now i have seen some guides about this but all of those have empty directory's and in mine there is my current website.

I have made a backup of the current site so do i just delete those files and drag my /wordpress files to the public_html folder.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to move it, you can still have wordpress show up at http://example.com, while leaving your directory right where it is. Just follow the instructions [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) depending on how you want to do it.

Comment: But i should be fine when i delete the current website when i made a backup? Do i need to keep some files or just delete all?

Comment: Not being sure what your hosting company has set up, I can't say for sure. But you should be fine deleting all WORDPRESS files (see list here: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Files), of course leave your original subfolder in place, since you will need that.

Comment: i noticed that my current website is in a subdirectory aswell, example.com/nl/ so it gets redirected somehow because when i just type example.com it will go the website so where do i have those redirects set? any idea?

Comment: You should not have to worry about those redirects or virtual servers, I assume they were setup by your hosting company. Your root folder is for all intents and purposes the root of your site, so that it how you should work with it.

Comment: Thanks ill try your tips out and hope for the best ;) thanks for your time. I can't give you a +1 since i do not have 15 rep on this wordpress stack.

Comment: Okay if anyone can help me that would be great! I followed the steps on the link but now somehow my site zilvertron.com looks really weird and i can not login to the backpanel where i changed something it the settings / general tab

Comment: you might need to go in to delete the .htaccess file via SFTP (in both the top level and lower level). And you are sure you followed all the other steps?

Comment: i think i did but somehow the site looks like this now www.zilvertron.com it is the old website but all messed up and i cant get in the backpanel now

Comment: are you saying the admin isn't showing up or that you can't login? The WP admin is showing up fine for me http://www.zilvertron.com/wp-admin

Comment: That links redirects now to zilvertron.com/wordpress and not the actual zilvertron.com

Comment: okay so i got it back to where i started i think using define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

Comment: hm, usually those are NOT defined in the wp_config.php file...those are defined in your DB. And btw, you ADMIN url (wp address url) will NOT be the same as your site url

Comment: The thing is my current site is www.zilvertron.com/nl/ but shows up as zilvertron.com my new website is zilvertron.com/wordpress/ now in all the guides you change the general settings just remove the /nl/ in my case drop all the files of /wordpress/ in the public_html folder and tadaa it is done. But in my case in the public_htlm is the /nl/ folder and also .htacces and index files